# Hibernate sometimes doesn't extract uuid referenced entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have two entities, let's name them `University` and `Student`, `Student` is unidirectional `ManyToOne` with `University` they both extends base class `BasicUUIDEntity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BasicUUIDEntity implements Serializable {

    protected UUID id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "binary(16)")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        BasicUUIDEntity that = (BasicUUIDEntity) o;

        return id == null || id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

The structure of `Student` and `University` doesn't really matters, the important things is:
Student.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public static class Student extends BasicUUIDEntity {

    private University univ;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "univ_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public University getUniversity() {
        return univ;
    }

    public void setUniversity(University univ) {
        this.univ = univ;
    }
}
```

University.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "universities")
public static class University extends BasicUUIDEntity {
    //of course it does contain some fields, but they are strings, etc.
}
```

The tables are created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
  id                 BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  univ_id            BINARY(16),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT_UNIV
  FOREIGN KEY (univ_id) REFERENCES memory_type (id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE universities
(
  id                 BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

The Issue is sometimes, on really rare occasions Hibernate doesn't extract that `University` entity along with `Student`, meaning that when I do `student.getUniversity()` it returns `null`, and in debugger it is also `null`. BUT the `students` table contains exactly the same `univ_id` as expected `University` of this `student`, and so does university contains that `id`. I am completely sure that hibernate session is not closed, and I've tried to execute exactly the same query as hibernate does, and it does return expected `id` of the university, joins them, etc. The thing is that most of the time It does work well, and such issue happens very rarely due to unknown reasons, what is more strange is that the table does contains that id, so it seems like it is not an MySQL issue.
Also worth mention, I am using Spring Data JPA.
Have anyone encountered such behavior? Could it be due to Inheritance/Data JPA/Java 9/Anything other?

PS.
Please ignore any typo in the code, it is just an example

Versions:

```
Hibernate: 5.2.12.Final, 
Spring Data JPA: 2.0.5.RELEASE,
HikariCP: 2.7.8,
MySQL connector: 6.0.6,
Java: 9
MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21
```

Comment: No idea if this is related to your problem, but your equals method seems to be broken when you get Hibernate Proxies since `getClass` will return the proxies class not the entities class.

Comment: @JensSchauder Good notice, much appreciated, I will try to change it and see if it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, finally

**tl;dr**

Put `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `ManyToOne` relation, so in my example it becomes:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "univ_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public University getUniversity() {
    return univ;
}
```

**Description**

I am not still sure why it behaves like this, but it seems that Hibernate does not extract `many-to-one` relations at all, if they're eager. It have some sense as this way there will be circular dependencies, but I thought that `PersistenceSet` will deal with such issues. What is even more strange - just the same structure actually works without eager extraction if I use Long instead of UUID.